# Jig for making jumper leads?

Tags: jumper

Does anyone know of a tool that can make jumper wires to fit standard spacings for breadboards?

What I have in mind is a jig where you dial in the number of rows you want the jumper to span, insert your chosen single-core wire, and the tool cuts a piece of wire to length, strips the ends and maybe even bends them.

I've bought jumper lead kits before, but I'm not a fan of them because they always seem to have one colour per length. I'd prefer to keep my 'traces' the same colour, which is hard to do with such a kit.

Comment: hmm.  that would be useful

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is a sort of *lead forming tool*. The most common such tools don't strip wire, as they're usually used for components such as resistors.

The usual hobbyist version I've seen is [a plastic device having a series of grooves in 0.1" increments](http://www.flickr.com/photos/lenore-m/857277446/). Perhaps you could use one of those as a cutting-and-stripping guide before bending.

Googling around, [the CM-01 on this page](http://www.controlsignals.net/component-preparation.html) claims to be able to form insulated jumpers and isn't obviously overkill, but I didn't find a price.

I also found various hand tools which automatically cut and bend, or just bend, to an adjustable width, but that would probably make stripping the short ends difficult. I also found high-priced fully-automatic jumper forming machines.

Perhaps a little more research starting with these keywords might turn up something useful.

Comment: [Hand held lead forming tool](http://uk.farnell.com/abeco/tp12/cut-form-tool-lead-small/dp/441065)

Comment: Close, but not exactly what I'm looking for. The plastic thingy is interesting though....

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can buy the individual parts to make the connectors, and crimp them onto any wire you like. [Pololu](http://www.pololu.com/) sells the parts to do this ([sockets](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1930),
[pins](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1931), and
[housings](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/category/70)).

In terms of crimping the connectors, you can go anywhere from a $200 tool for crimping an entire housing in one go, to a $30 single crimper, to an effectively free pliers and patience approach.

Alternatively, they also sell [pre-crimped connectors](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/category/71), in a random selection of colors.

#### EDIT:

Oops, I seem to be thinking about the wrong type of jumper cable. Oh well.

Comment: How do you escape dollar symbols?

Comment: dollar symbols are the delimiter for $LaTeX$ math markup.  You can create a dollar sign with LaTex with this syntax: `$\$$` $\rightarrow\mbox{ }\$$

Comment: Isn't there a way of typing a dollar that doesn't invoke the $\LaTeX$ markup?

Comment: no. The latex markup expects the dollar sign. There is a request in to change this but do not get your hopes up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm four years late to this question - but this "Wire stripping guage" from BreadBoardManiac looks like the closest you can get for the time being.  It screws onto a normal pair of wire strippers, and lets you easily measure off how much to strip.
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/252587878/stress-free-great-tool-for-breadboard-wire-strippi/description

Permanent product page is here:
https://wakutuku.com/shop/breadboardmaniac/bbm-wsg.html

Still, I would love to have a one-squeeze device that cuts, strips, and bends.  Maybe I'll design one someday if I'm bored. :-)